# vector of object (How to start)

Tags: c++, vector

I am very confuse about vector of object in c++ 
could any one give me any tip to understand how to take objects as vector .
my question is very very simple but i do not know why i am confuse.

Q.define a bank class, containing a vector of bank accounts, with methods to add a new account and to print all the accounts.

Add a method to deposit a specified amount into the account of a named customer, and another to similarly withdraw. Use your print method to test them.

please help me at start because i do not want lose the concept at the start.

Comment: Provide what you have reached, by code.

Comment: Hint: `vector` has template support.

Comment: `class bank_account {}; class bank { std::vector<bank_account> accounts; };`

Comment: If this is too much for you, go to the book list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list and get one of the Beginner books.

Comment: `std::vector<account> accounts;` is what you want. Your introductory book should describe how `vector` works; otherwise, there are online references like [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), but you're not going to get far without a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242).

Comment: If you want to be able to easily get the account of a named customer, this sounds more like the job for a std::map

Comment: @BrianSchlenker And even more for a database

Comment: @Paranaix And even more like homework for the part of the course that introduces `vector`, where you would fail if you didn't follow the specification.

Comment: @molbdnilo Hey I havent started with this :D I know the purpose of the assignment. Although if somebody already proposes a better implementation we should atleast provide the most common implementation

Answer (score 1):

Vector is a list of objects. To create a vector of bank accounts, you can go with :

```
vector<BankAccount> accountList;
```

The type between the <> (BankAccount) is to indicate the vector what type of object it must store.

To add an object to the vector, you have :

```
accountList.push_back(myBankAccount);
```

Where myBankAccount is an instanciation of the BankAccount class.

The documentation for the vector class is here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

You just have to create a Bank object which owns a vector object, the latter storing the BankAccount objects.

Comment: 1. I don't think `add` is valid syntax for vectors 2. You may want to define copy constructor if you care about deep/shallow copy. Vector to pointer to the objects may be better from a performance point of view.

Comment: @Bill Whether a vector of pointers is performance wise better depends much on how it is used and if the underlying object can be moved. With such a task which is just an exercise the performance aspect is completely meanigless (and even not answereable for us) and I would thus rate your suggestion as premature optimization (or deoptimization). One should usually always go with RAII if he doesnt have an important reason for pointers.

Comment: Right, I edited to correct the add problem. Of course storing pointers are better than storing objects, I wanted to keep it very simple but indeed, maybe I should not teach bad practices.

Comment: @Paranaix Yes, I agree to some extent. But, I wanted to point out the problem of deep and shallow copy when you assign objects in vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be enough for you to "start":

```
struct Account
{
    std::string name;
};

struct Bank
{

    void Add(const Account& acc)
    {
        // insert into vector here, you better find out how to do this by your own
    }

private:
    std::vector<Account> m_accounts;

};
```

Comment: why we use & as you used in (const Account& acc)

Comment: @Arshad its just good habit as it prevents an unneccessary copy. Notice that the account is though copied atleast once as we have to push it in the vector.

Comment: i do not understand what you means please explain more

Comment: @Arshad No I wont, read it up in a c++ book, im not your teacher or tutor. Read up the following topics: copy construction, RAII, references